# Deploying to App Engine generates error with gulp?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gulp, google-cloud-platform

What I wrote in terminal to deploy as usual:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

---

The error I get:

```
Application startup error:

> meanjs@0.5.0 start /app
> gulp

sh: 1: gulp: not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! meanjs@0.5.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meanjs@0.5.0 start script 'gulp'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the meanjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs meanjs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meanjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
```

---

Using Mean.js : https://github.com/meanjs/mean

Can't find the npm debug log.

---

**P.S.:** I did install gulp globally with

```
$ sudo npm install gulp-cli -g
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was an issue with the NODE_ENV.

It would not find the gulp dependency in production, so I had to change my package.json and put everything in "dependencies" instead of using some in "dev_dependencies".

Comment: Exact same problem but this does not solve it.  What value did you set on NODE_ENV?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to use sudo.

You can fix your error by typing this in terminal:

```
npm config set prefix ~/npm

# add this to your .bashrc (or .zshrc or whatever you are using)
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/npm/bin"
```

Then re-install without sudo.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not install gulp in your server. Try to re-install gulp in your server with NodeJS and npm on your server and then install gulp with required packages it may resolve an error.

Please review an error you may find a solution

> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed.

Install gulp in your project

> npm install gulp

Install gulp globally.

> npm install gulp -g